# rails combining two models in form form without association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I  have 2 models PrimeAccount and Ticket.
I want to create Ticket in the PrimeAccount new form.
I am trying this in PrimeAccount controller

```
def create
    ticket = Ticket.new(ticket_params)
    # ticket.event_id = params[:event_id]
    ticket.save!
    .............
 end

 def ticket_params
      params.permit(:price, :quantity, :event_id)
 end

 def prime_account_params
      params.permit(:country)
 end
```

I am confused how to write new form so that it will accept both ticket and prime account fields.

Also in url I am sending event params like

> http://localhost:3000/prime_accounts/new?event_id=11

I want to pass `event_id` into `ticket_params`.

please tell me how to create new form.

Comment: Your main objective is to create `Ticket` in the `PrimeAccount new form` or to pass `event_id` into `ticket_params` or both?

Comment: Can you post your model associations as well

Comment: @Pavan as i said above "event has_many tickets" and user has_one prime_account. Thats it. no other association